# Use select change to fadeout or fadein another field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a dropdown which as 2 values yes/no to change whether a field is displayed or not. I still want element to exist just no visible.

I am using Razor and MVC3 to render the page.

So I have tried the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $("DiscountOn").change(function () {
        if ($("DiscountOn").Value == 0) {
            $("DiscountPercentage").fadeOut('fast');
        }
        else {
            $("DiscountPercentage").fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

DiscountOn is the dropdown which has values of either 0 or 1, text no or yes respectively. I want it to make DiscountPercentage dissappear when DiscountOn is turned to 0 and reappear when DiscountOn is turned 1. And for value added, if you can make it appear or or disappear when the page has loaded depending on which option is set in the dropdown that would be excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("DiscountOn")
```

does not select the element properly. If the ID of the element that you wish to select then you need to either do:

```
document.getElementById("DiscountOn") // Pure JS
```

or

```
$("#DiscountOn") // jQuery
```

Your other problem is how you are getting the value. You either need to do this

```
.value // Pure JS
```

or

```
.val() // jQuery
```

Remember that JS is case-sensitive!

Comment: One question, it still doesn't work, I've put in an alert to see what the value is, however the alert doesn't even show up. All the ID's are correct.

Comment: IT DOES WORK, i recently updated my projects JQuery library but never specified it in cshtml

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("#DiscountOn").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '0') {
            $('#DiscountPercentage').fadeOut('fast');
        }
        else {
            $('#DiscountPercentage').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

> And for value added, if you can make it appear or or disappear when
>   the page has loaded depending on which option is set in the dropdown
>   that would be excellent.

Ideally this should be done on the server side and not using any javascript. You already know the selected value of the dropdown, so you could dynamically add some CSS class around the DiscountPercentage element to show/hide it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the selector

If `DiscountOn` and `DiscountPercentage` are IDs or the element. Prefix it with `#` if they are class then with `.`

```
$(function () {
    $("#DiscountOn").change(function () {
        if ($("#DiscountOn").val() === 0) {
            $("#DiscountPercentage").fadeOut('fast');
        }
        else {
            $("#DiscountPercentage").fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $("#DiscountOn").Value == 0, rly?

Comment: hmm, I didn't noticed If he made that mistake too. If you read my comment I only mentioned one problem and fixed that.